# How can I figure out why a Laravel Queue Worker is running?

Tags: laravel

A Laravel queue worker was producing a lot of error log entries due to the DB server crashing, in turn Laravel's log grew to 150gb within just two hours, filling up the entire hard drive so that several web apps stopped working.

But actually there is only a queue worker for sending emails in our system and no emails have been sent during the past days. So why is there still a queue worker running?

Are there other reasons why a queue worker might be accessing the DB in a Laravel system besides starting it "manually" (i.e. in our case - by the command that sends mails)?

We're currently using Laravel 5.1.

Comment: A Laravel queue doesn't start upon request unless it's driver is set to `sync`. You probably have a cron to run the `queue` periodically and it probably don't have `--tries` limit.

Comment: Do you have supervisord running in the background?

Answer (score 0):

First, the Laravel worker is using DB to store its job details.

And, you should indicate the maximum number of times a job should be attempted using:

`php artisan queue:listen connection-name --tries=3`

Then setup a provider to handle if any queued job fails.

For your main question, you should install [supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#supervisor-configuration), then you can have a UI to manage your workers.